# problems with form_tag for controller action with members-get route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for, link-to

I'm making a form_tag panel that contains information (checkboxes) specific to a controller action. This action is set up in "routes.rb" as follows:

```
resources :students do
  collection do
    get :send_student_report_pdf
  end   
end
```

This setup **works** perfectly when I call the action from a link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Download PDF Report", :action => 'send_student_report_pdf', :controller => 'students'%>
```

However when I used it in a `form_tag`, it keeps giving me this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/students/send_student_report_pdf"
```

The `form_tag` code I have is here:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'students', :action => 'send_student_report_pdf', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= label_tag "Include columns" %> <br>
  <%= check_box_tag "first_name", params[:first_name], checked = true %> <%= label_tag "First Name" %><br>  
  <%= submit_tag "Download PDF Report", :action => 'send_student_report_pdf', :controller => 'students'%>  
<% end %>
```

I have tried giving it the url, path like:

```
<%= form_tag send_student_report_pdf_students_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

But it has been consistently giving me the same Route error (as if the action doesn't exist at all in routes.rb, even though it works perfectly using `link_to` instead of `form_tag submit`

Here is the code for the action in the controller, it basically sends back a file.

```
def send_student_report_pdf
  @students = search_sort_and_paginate
  puts "params[:first_name] = ", params[:first_namea]
  send_data(generate_pdf_report(@students), :filename => "report.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf') 
end
```

If you see that I'm missing something here, please help me.

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `:method => 'get'` part in your form_for is in the url_for_options hash, not the options hash, so Rails will be putting it onto the url as cgi params instead. Try changing it to this:

```
form_tag url_for(:controller => 'students', :action => 'send_student_report_pdf'), :method => 'get' do ...
```

The reason you can't use the named route is because you didn't name it in your routes. If you name it in your routes and use the named route in your form_tag, you won't need to use url_for...

```
resources :students do
  collection do
    get :send_student_report_pdf, :as => :send_student_report_pdf
  end   
end
```

You can check whether your routes are as you expect by running `rake routes`

Comment: Wow, this works awesome! Thanks a lot for you help. I have a smaller question about sharing the parameters of "form_tag" (such as check_box_tag on/off, text_field_tag values) with the controllers. I tried: <%= check_box_tag "first_name", params[:first_name], checked = true %>. But in the controller when I tried getting the value of "params[:first_name], I didn't get anything back. Thanks a lot, though, your original answer really helped me !

Comment: Watch your development log. It'll tell you what params have been sent to an action, which will help you see how you'd need to reference it.

Comment: Cool. I figured it out by adding :value => params[:first_name] to the check_box_tag. Now params[:first_name] appears in the controller action. Thanks for your help.